# ASP.Net HyperLink and Download directly?

Tags: asp.net

want to have a Hyperlink-Button in a gridView in which I can display a Link for a direct download of files.

So far I am okay, but when I link the file in the NavigateURL, I don't get the file via click, I must right click -> Save as!
That I don't want. Any help?

Comment: What exactly happens when you click the link? Does nothing happen? Does it open in the browser instead of opening the "save as" dialog?

Comment: Nope, nothing happen. I wish to have the Save As Dialog

Comment: What request is the browser sending?  What is the server's response?  Without experiencing this issue before, I don't think there is enough information yet to answer your question.  Use Fiddler or a similar tool and tell us what the HTTP request and response looks like.  Is the behavior identical between browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an ashx file handler.  Your ashx takes the request through the querystring, loads the proper file into memory, sets the proper response headers and streams the file to the browser:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE);  //You need to specify this
context.Response.ContentType = YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE;  //And this
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
context.Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
context.Response.Flush();
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

This lets you have some fine-grain control over the content that is being delivered if you have any concerns about security or maybe keeping track of who has downloaded what file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a browser issue.  Possibly the browser is trying to open up some application to handle this and failing.  Double-check your application associations and/or try a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would add also "Content-Disposition" header to response:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + filename);
```