# Download file / Save as in .Net not working

Tags: asp.net, http, download, mime-types, content-disposition

I've got a jquery lightbox based screen which I want to download a file when a link button is clicked, but the popup box allowing me to save is not appearing... The simple test code I've got below works if put it in the form load but not if I put it in the server side click event of the Hyperlink. Any ideas why?

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=event.txt");
Response.Write("test");
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Looking through firebug, the Response Headers are as below, but the actual response is just the html for the page as it reloads.

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   private
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=event.txt
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Fri, 03 Jun 2011 03:21:25 GMT
```

Comment: Have you set your hyperlink's `OnClick` attribute to your download event handler in the code behind? Alternatively, you could use an `ashx file handler` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703066/asp-net-hyperlink-and-download-directly

Comment: The OnClick attribute is linked up and it's containing code executed ... I'll look into ashx handlers. Im not familiar with them ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an experiment I tried:

Markup:

```
<p>
    <a href="#" runat="server" ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download Text" onServerClick="DownloadFile">Download</a>
</p>
```

Code behind:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=event.txt");
Response.Write("test");
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

}

The only thing different is I used OnServerClick instead of OnClick.

This works for me on Firefox 3.6 and IE9.